# Swift: Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type on init

Tags: ios, arrays, swift5, xcode11.4

I have Struct init and I'm trying to filter the an array in init:

```
public struct doSomething: Codable {
    public var listOfStuff: [String]

    init(someStuff: [String]) {
        var clone = someStuff
        let stuff: [String] = clone.removeAll { $0 == "myName"}
        listOfStuff = stuff
    }
}
```

On this line `let stuff: [String] = clone.removeAll { $0 == "myName"}` I'm getting this error:

`error: cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type '[String]`
[image]
Any of you knows why I'm getting this error or if you know a work around?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

[removeAll](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017530-removeall) does not return a value. That's the same thing as returning [`Void`, which is the same thing as `()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/void).

```swift
clone.removeAll { $0 == "myName" }
listOfStuff = clone
```

Better yet, don't even use it.

```swift
init(someStuff: [String]) {
  listOfStuff = someStuff.filter { $0 != "myName" }
}
```